# Python dictionary doesn't have all the keys assigned, or items

Tags: python, dictionary

I created the following dictionary

```
exDict = {True: 0, False: 1, 1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

and when I print `exDict.keys()`, well, it gives me a generator.  Ok, so I coerce it to a list, and it gives me

```
[False, True, 2]
```

Why isn't 1 there?  When I print `exDict.items()` it gives me

```
[(False, 1), (True, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

Anyone have a guess about what's going on here?  I'm stumped.

Comment: Nice head-scratcher! Python's designers try to avoid surprises, but you can't get them all...

Comment: you have the solution in your items: `(True, 'a')`, which is the value for `1`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This happens because `True == 1` (and `False == 0`, but you didn't have `0` as a key).  You'll have to refactor your code or data somehow, because a `dict` considers keys to be the same if they are "equal" (rather than `is`).

Comment: But there is no certainty which one would be shown, as the dict is unordered, right?

Comment: I'm not certain if there is certainty.  I wouldn't rely on it anyway.

Comment: @heemayl even though the order of items in a dict isn't guaranteed, I think the key it uses will be the first one encountered. It won't replace a key when it finds an existing one that's equivalent.

Comment: @heemayl : contrary to what Mark Ransom suggested, in current 2.7.x and 3.x the final value is the **last** one encountered of an equivalent key (in your example it's `a`) . This also makes sense, if we consider that the dictionary is probably constructed iteratively from the literal, so "later" mappings overwrite the "earlier" ones.

Comment: I wish multiple instances of the same key in a `dict` literal caused a runtime error.

Comment: Is it wise to eg inherit and modify the dict class to get around this? Or are boolean dict keys just a bad idea. My feeling is the latter.

Comment: @mikołak, I wasn't talking about the *value*, I was talking about the *key*. I just tested Python 2.7.10 and it works the way I said, retaining the original key. It also works the way you said, retaining the last value.

Comment: @jpmc26 dicts would be much less useful if you couldn't overwrite previous contents. Initializing the whole thing with a literal doesn't happen often enough for your wish to catch many errors.

Comment: @MarkRansom : ah, sorry, I parsed that as "replace [the value assigned to] a key".

Answer (score 12):

What you are seeing is python coercing the `1` to be equal to the `True`.

You'll see that the dictionary you print is:

```
False  1
True   a
2      b
```

Where the value `a` was meant to be assigned to the `1`, but instead the value for `True` got reassigned to `a`.

According to the [Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> The Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type, and **Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1**, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

Emphasis mine.

Note: In python 2.X `True` and `False` can be re-assigned, so this behavior cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 5):

Python take the 1 as `True`. And the Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type

```
In [1]: a = {}

In [2]: a[True] = 0

In [3]: 1 in a.keys()
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insert a key-value pair in a `dict` python checks if the key already exists and if it exists it will replace the current value.

This check does something like this:

```
def hash_and_value_equal(key1, key2):
    return hash(key1) == hash(key2) and key1 == key2
```

So not only must the values be equal but also their `hash`. Unfortunatly for you `True` and `1` but also `False` and `0` will be considered equal keys:

```
>>> hash_and_value_equal(0, False)
True

>>> hash_and_value_equal(1, True)
True
```

and therefore they replace the value (**but** not the key):

```
>>> a = {1: 0}
>>> a[True] = 2
>>> a
{1: 2}

>>> a = {False: 0}
>>> a[0] = 2
>>> a
{False: 2}
```

I've showed the case of adding a key manually but the steps taken are the same when using the `dict literal`:

```
>>> a = {False: 0, 0: 2}
>>> a
{False: 2}
```

or the `dict`-builtin:

```
>>> a = dict(((0, 0), (False, 2)))
>>> a
{0: 2}
```

---

This can be very important if you write own classes and want to use them as potential keys inside dictionaries. Depending on your implementation of `__eq__` and `__hash__` these will and won't replace the values of equal but not identical keys:

```
class IntContainer(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other

    def __hash__(self):
        # Just offsetting the hash is enough because it also checks equality
        return hash(1 + self.value)

>>> hash_equal(1, IntContainer(1))
False

>>> hash_equal(2, IntContainer(1))
False
```

So these won't replace existing integer keys:

```
>>> a = {1: 2, IntContainer(1): 3, 2: 4}
>>> a
{1: 2, <__main__.IntContainer at 0x1ee1258fe80>: 3, 2: 4}
```

or something that is considered as identical key:

```
class AnotherIntContainer(IntContainer):
    def __hash__(self):
        # Not offsetted hash (collides with integer)
        return hash(self.value)

>>> hash_and_value_equal(1, AnotherIntContainer(1))
True
```

These will now replace the integer keys:

```
>>> a = {1: 2, AnotherIntContainer(1): 5}
>>> a
{1: 5}
```

The only really important thing is to keep in mind that dictionary keys are consered equal if the objects and their hash is equal.